# asp.net mvc c# image upload page crashing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am uploading an image ,when uploading image of a very large size the application crashes . i am checking the image size as well . but uploading image of a very large size bypass everything and crashes the application. What do u people suggest? what is the best practise?

Comment: Where does it crash? On a line of your code? A stack trace or some code may help.

Comment: it doesn't go on any line of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET's default max upload file size is 4MB. To upload larger files you need to add the following configuration in web.config file:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="10240" />
</system.web>
```

This will set max file upload size to 10MB. You can also use it in `location` tag to apply the configuration only on specific directory.